# Speeding up the Kendo UI Grid Rendering ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI Grid for a table.  When the page loads, I see the initial HTML table for a slight second before its re-drawn using the Kendo UI grid.  I have the css reference at the top and the

```
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```

just after the jquery script reference at the bottom of the page.  Its a clunky UX to have a standard HTML table load then see the conversion, there must be a fix for this.

Any suggestions? Much appreciated!

Comment: Update: I read that changing debug to false for production helps as does bundling.  Both have been implemented, only a slight change in performance.  Is there a technique maybe to delay the page load until it draws the grid?  Seems like a great product like Kendo UI would not have this type of lag time to redraw the table?

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the DOM has been loaded, then show the div containing the table. You can always have a loading gif show prior to page load, then hide that/show the table. If you need additional information, let me know. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Kryptonkal.  Do you have any good examples for this approach?